# Play Framwork Java hot reloading fails for Multi module app

Tags: java, playframework, hot-reload

my application using Java framework (v2.8.16) sbt (v1.5.5), Play-Ebean plugin (v6.2.0-RC7),  and have multi-module setup. In Play's development mode there is a hot code reloading feature that seems to get fail when one class from Module A extend/implements class from Module B

its a error like

```
oader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @5d340c5; controllers.moduleB.ModuleBClass is in unnamed module of loader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @4263d364)
at controllers.moduleA.ModuleAClass.method(ModuleAClass.java:18)
```

ModuleA included ModuleB like that (from build.sbt)

```
lazy val modB: sbt.ProjectReference = RootProject(file("../moduleB"))

lazy val moduleA = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(ABC, XYZ)
    .dependsOn(modB % "compile->compile;test->test")
```